# PHP - having trouble with calling a char[] array

Tags: php

```
 char[]  validChars= {'2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 
   'C',
   'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K','L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T',   

   'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'}

 bool VerifyKey(string key)
  {
  if (key.Length != 10)
   return false;
   char checkDigit = GenerateCheckCharacter(key.ToUpper().Substring(0,
    9 ));
   return key[9] == checkDigit;
   }
   // Implementation of Luhn Mod N algorithm for check digit.
   char GenerateCheckCharacter(string input)
   {
   int factor = 2;
   int sum = 0;
   int n = validChars.Length;
   // Starting from the right and working leftwards is easier since
  // the initial "factor" will always be "2"
  for (int i = input.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
   {
  int codePoint = Array.IndexOf(validChars, input[i]);
  int addend = factor * codePoint;
  // Alternate the "factor" that each "codePoint" is multiplied by
  factor = (factor == 2) ? 1 : 2;
 // Sum the digits of the "addend" as expressed in base "n"
 addend = (addend / n) + (addend % n);
  sum += addend;
  }
 // Calculate the number that must be added to the "sum"
 // to make it divisible by "n"
 int remainder = sum % n;
 int checkCodePoint = (n - remainder) % n;
 return validChars[checkCodePoint];
 }
```

### I am using this code to validate a string, I am calling validChars and I am getting the following error when trying to call the above method within php

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'validChars' (T_STRING) in your code on line 46.##

## I am performing a call like this ' validChars('W56HFY6')'; The below lines show the above mentioned error

```
   char[]  validChars= {'2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 
   'C',
   'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K','L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T',   

   'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'}
```

Comment: This is not php-code.

Answer (score 1):

this is not a php array but this:

```
$validChars = array('2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K','L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z');
```